# nodeJs/Express dealing with missing static files

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, static-files

I have a node App. That is configured to serve static files by:

    `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));`

And I use some auth middlewares on other routes. The problem comes up when I hit an image that doesn't exist on the server. In this case looks like express is trying to send that request through all of the middlewares that I have for NON-static content. 
Is there a way to just send 404 for missing static asset, rather than re-trigger all middlewares per missing file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way that the `express.static()` middleware works by default is that it looks for the file in the target directory and if it is not found, then it passes it on to the next middleware.

But, it has a `fallthrough` option that if you set it to `false`, then it will immediately 404 any missing file that was supposed to be in the static directory.

From [the `express.static()` doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static):

> fallthrough
>
> When this option is true, client errors such as a bad request or a
>   request to a non-existent file will cause this middleware to simply
>   call next() to invoke the next middleware in the stack. When false,
>   these errors (even 404s), will invoke next(err).
>
> Set this option to true so you can map multiple physical directories
>   to the same web address or for routes to fill in non-existent files.
>
> Use false if you have mounted this middleware at a path designed to be
>   strictly a single file system directory, which allows for
>   short-circuiting 404s for less overhead. This middleware will also
>   reply to all methods.

Example:

```
app.use("/public", express.static("/static", {fallthrough: false}));
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like charm. I would also add this is a newish feature of **serve-static** module. I was using **express 4.2.0** and that feature wasn't available in the version of **serve-static** that comes with express. So needed to update.

Comment: @Max - I didn't realize it was only a newish feature - good to know.  The Express doc often doesn't identify what version features were added.